# Is asking to identify a food from a picture on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Here on the Black Sea in Romania people are eating a shellfish called in Romanian "rapane" which they translate as "oyster". But they are elongated spiral shells which to me look nothing like the chunky flattish oyster shells in Australia. Besides which there is another Romanian word "stridie" for oyster and I can't find "rapane" in my print dictionary or any online dictionary but I can find some pictures with Google Images.

So, if I take photos of the shells and the food and ask what it's called in English would that be an acceptable question for this site?

**EDIT**

I couldn't find a question where this was done but there is [this question asking to identify a food from a vague description](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12889/help-identify-a-strange-root-vegetable) and people asked for a photo to be added but none was.

Comment: The answers so far are in favour. I've only got photos of dead shells so far so I'll see if I can get photos of living creatures and cooked food too. If somebody could create a tag like [tag:identify] or [tag:identification] that would be great. You could even add it to these two posts: [1](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12889/help-identify-a-strange-root-vegetable), [2](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11834/what-is-this-fungus-lichen-in-my-garam-masala-trifle-truffle).

Comment: I haven't managed to take any better photos yet but [I've gone ahead and asked the question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16500/identify-this-seafood-from-the-black-sea-known-in-romanian-as-rapane) and will update the photos if I can take better ones:

Comment: Following [let's play the guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) the "identify-this" tags (and corresponding questions) have been removed on many sister sites.

Answer (score 9):

So, this type of question actually has a sort of history of its own on the Stack Exchange network; the controversy originally started on the Gaming site with [What is the point of "help me remember this game" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1455/7294), in which the following arguments were presented *against* the questions:

- They're very localized; it's unlikely that somebody else will find the question, *even if they have the same problem*;
- They have the faint air of trivia and are likely to inspire copycats;
- Answers rely on people's rote memory, rather than any skill or comprehension (Grace Note called this "passive knowledge").

Now I'm not saying that all or any of these are *strong* arguments, or even that they all apply to us, I'm just relating the history, so please hold onto your pitchforks until you've finished reading.

It was shortly afterward that Jeff (one of the site owners) wrote his post [The Pee-Wee Herman Rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).  To make a very long story very short, this post states:

- If the question doesn't suck too badly, and it looks as though the person who wrote it could potentially become a productive contributor, then we should make their first experience with our community a positive one and allow it.

It's almost like an *"everybody gets **one**"* rule of thumb; if you've [earned your bulls**t](http://everything2.com/title/Butterfinger+McFlurry), we'll give you a free pass. Or if you've just stumbled in here, disoriented, but seem like the kind of person we might want to hang out with, we'll let you keep it as an incentive to stay.

I'm still just telling the story.  Put away the pitchforks.

This subject then hit the Sci-Fi site and was discussed in the meta question [Are book / movie / TV series identification questions allowed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/376)  Their community had a very different take on it:

- They fit the Q&A format better than a lot of other questions that get asked; they have exactly *one* correct answer and not much room extended discussion.
- Their community had gotten pretty efficient at answering them, so the rote memory/passive knowledge argument seemed to be moot;
- "Story ID" questions brought in *huge* traffic to Usenet groups - even after those groups became infested with spam and off-topic discussion.

I'd add a few more reasons in *favour* of the questions on Seasoned Advice:

- Both the Gaming and SciFi sites are about entertainment. A food is a real item that people can use.  The audience will learn *far* more than just trivia from an "identify-this-food" question.  (Well, as long as it's not something mind-numbingly obvious, like a carrot or a bulb of garlic).
- People are a lot more like to be familiar with an ingredient than they are with a story or a game.  It's not really that localized.  Chances are that the majority of people within several large geographical areas have seen this ingredient repeatedly in grocery stores, even if they don't know what it is either.
- Ingredients are produced by nature, and there are a finite number of them.  There may be *some* answers from rote memory, but part of being an expert cook is learning to choose and recognize ingredients.  A person's ability to answer an identify-this-food question *does* or *should* correlate with his/her skill and experience as a cook.  Sort of like a geologist being able to identify rocks - it's actually part of the job.

That pretty much defeats *all* of the original arguments posed *against* ID questions, and the arguments *in favour* still apply to us.  So I would *unequivocally* say that **yes, we should always consider these questions on topic, and only close them if they have serious unrelated problems.**

That being said, I'd like for members to follow a few guidelines when asking these questions (and, @hippietrail, I think you've already got the right idea):

- Include as **detailed a description** as you can muster.  Size, shape, colour, texture, taste, smell, weight, density, where you found it, when you found it (seasonal?), etc. If you know the name in a different language but can't translate it, that's great to include too.  This is partly to help people answer it but also to help other people **find it**. The more searchable your question is, the more likely it is to help some future visitor.
- *Definitely* include a **photo** if you can; multiple photos if it has an odd shape.  This won't help anyone find the question but it is by far the *most* effective way to communicate your question to potential answerers.
- If you can - and this is especially important in cases where there's no photo - **list some or all of the foods that you know are *similar* but not the same**, and explain the differences.  This will help *you* to receive fewer false positives and avoid wasting time explaining why various shot-in-the-dark answers are wrong.

It's very important to **be specific**.  I'm saying here that the questions are *on topic*, but if we see a hopelessly vague description that could refer to any of a dozen different types of foods, we probably *will* close it as Not A Real Question.

As long as you're prepared to be detailed - go for it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I would consider that on topic.

And here is an [identical type of question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11834/what-is-this-fungus-lichen-in-my-garam-masala-trifle-truffle) on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I agree too that this is on topic. It is about food, and it doesn't hurt the FAQ. It isn't exactly general reference, because dictionaries don't list obscure dishes or ingredients. Of course, it is up to the asker to make sure that it is a good question (provide enough information for an answer to be possible, etc.), but this is true for any other type of question. So count another positive vote.

Disclaimer: I may be biased, because I know the answer to your rapane question. But I tried to view that as objectively as possible, imagining questions to which I don't know the answers.

Comment: Now you're teasing! (-;

Comment: Don't worry, if they don't let you ask on the main site, I'll tell you here or in chat. The point is, if the question is legitimate, I'd like you to put it on the parent page, where other people can find it later.

Comment: OK I've just got to get some more photos as I only have photos of shells so far but I know a guy who dives for them every day and is a cook in one of the restaurants... Or I might ask with what I already have and add more when I get them...

Comment: @hippietrail, I posted it in chat. Don't know if you get a notification if you haven't chatted before.